# Simplifying the equation $\log y = 10 + 0.5x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve for $y$. When expressed in simplest form, what familiar kind of equation results?
>   $$\log y = 10 + 0.5x$$

For this question, I would get rid of log first right? So, I would get

$$\begin{align*}
10^{\log y}&= 10^{10 +0.5x}\\
y &= 10^{10 + 0.5x}? 
\end{align*}$$
     Yea... I don't know what I'm doing.. I don't think that's the answer.

Can someone help explain?

Comment: All your work so far is good. You can simplify it a little further using the property $a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$

Answer (score 3):

$y = 10^{10 + 0.5x} = 10^{10} \times 10^{0.5x}  = 10^{10} \times (10^{0.5})^x
= 10.000.000.000 \times (\sqrt{10})^x$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Please read [this tutorial on how to use LaTeX to nicely format your mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. If I've surmised the goal of the question correctly, these are the manipulations you're supposed to do:
$$\begin{align*}
y &= 10^{10 + 0.5x} \\
y &= 10^{10}\cdot 10^{0.5x}\\
y &= 10^{10}\cdot e^{0.5\ln(10)x}\\
y &= Ce^{ax}
\end{align*}$$
where $C=10^{10}$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}\ln(10)$. The form $y=Ce^{ax}$ represents exponential growth/decay. ([See here for example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialGrowth.html).)